# Is this proof for $11^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$ correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Show that $11^{10} \equiv 1\pmod{100}$

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409057/show-that-1110-equiv-1-mod-100), I asked a question about this same problem and all the answers say that I prove this by binomial expansion.

But by doing binomial expansion to show this is the same as doing $11^{10}$ mod $\ 100$ in the calculator, no property is being showed to prove this.

But I think this proof might be right.

$\gcd(11, 100) = 1$

$11^{φ(100)} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$

$11^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$  $\ ⇒$

$11^{10} *11^{10} *11^{10}* 11^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$

by Looking everybody mod $\ 100$, I can say that $11^{10} \equiv 1\pmod{100}$

Comment: I don't understand your argument..  For instance, $3^{40}\equiv 1 \pmod {100}$ too, but $3^{10}\equiv 49$.

Comment: I am confused! Why you posted [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409057/show-that-1110-equiv-1-mod-100/2409109#2409109) again when you have a lots of solution there!

Comment: @lulu thanks, as the euler's theorem can't help in this proof, What other method could help to prove this ?

Comment: @MANMAID because I think binomial expansion can't prove this by arithmetic properties.

Comment: Honestly, the binomial theorem is by far the best way to go here.  And despite what you say it is much easier to do it by hand that way than by any other straight forward means.  Alternatively, you can search the factors of $40$ to find the order of $11\pmod {100}$.

Comment: I simply don't understand your objection to using the binomial theorem.  It solves the problem in one line, using simple arithmetic.  What more could anyone hope for?

Comment: In the future, if you have questions about a specific proof, you should add the (proof-verification) tag.

Comment: Although using binomial expansion is the best way to solve, have you seen my solution anyway?

Comment: @MANMAID Yes, I read all the answers. But none was clear to me, But anyways thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because the solutions to $x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$ are $$x \equiv 1, 7, 43, 49, 51, 57, 93, 99 \pmod{100}.$$ So from $$ (11^{10})^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{100} $$ the best you can say is that $$ 11^{10} \equiv 1, 7, 43, 49, 51, 57, 93, \text{ or } 99 \pmod{100}. $$

Answer (score 0):

$100=2^25^2;11^{10}=(11^2)^5;11^2\equiv 1 \bmod {(2^2,5^2)}$ so we have that $(11^2)^5\equiv 1^5 \bmod {(2^2,5^2)}$ and since $\gcd\!\!(2^2,5^2)=1$ we have by CRT etc. that it's 1 mod their product which is 100.

Answer (score 0):

Use not $11^{10}$ directly, but $(11^2)^5$ where $11^2\equiv (20+1) \bmod 100$.  Put $(20+1)^5$ into the usual binomial power formula for $(a+b)^n$ and, seeing that the middle term binomial coefficients are all multiples of $5$, infer that all terms are multiples of $100$ except the final $1$.